# Adding marker on current location

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps

I'm a beginner in android programming and I'm currently working on google maps. What I want to do is to get the current location of the user and then put a marker on that location.

I'm practicing on this but I really can't get it to work. This only shows the current location of the user. But what I want to do is to display a marker on it as well. Any suggestions how to do it?

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener,
    OnMapReadyCallback,
    ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {

private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
private boolean mPermissionDenied = false;
private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this);
    enableMyLocation();
}

private void enableMyLocation() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        PermissionUtils.requestPermission(this, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, true);
    } else if (mMap != null) {

        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Showing current location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    return false;
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode != LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
        return;
    }

    if (PermissionUtils.isPermissionGranted(permissions, grantResults,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

        enableMyLocation();
    } else {

        mPermissionDenied = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: In the documentation section: [Show Current Location in a Google Map](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/170/google-maps-api-v2-for-android/5557/show-current-location-in-a-google-map)

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen Thanks! Got it working now.

Answer (score 0):

Get you last location-

- LatLng location = getLatLngFromLastLocation();

Then use this code block to put marker on map:

```js
MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(location)
                .icon(getMarkerIcon(mProfileTheme.getColorCodeLight()));

public BitmapDescriptor getMarkerIcon(int color) {
        float[] hsv = new float[3];
        Color.colorToHSV(color, hsv);
        return BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(hsv[0]);
    }
```